# NodeJS python-shell i

Tags: python, node.js

i want to run a python script via nodejs with python-shell to simply turn a led via my raspberry pi on. The script works pretty well, but i cant run it via the nodejs

my NodeJS:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

PythonShell.run('ledtest.py', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('finished');
});
```

my PythonScript:

```
import serial
import time

s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
s.close()
s.open()
time.sleep(5)


s.write("1")
time.sleep(2)
s.write("0")
```

error

```
  events.js:160
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    Error: spawn python ENOENT
        at exports._errnoException (util.js:953:11)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:182:32)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:577:11)
        at startup (node.js:160:18)
        at node.js:449:3
```

thanks for suggestions

Comment: If you are going to run python code, why not use Flask?

Comment: my python architecture is 32 bit and nodejs is arm. maybe this could be the course?

Comment: Python comes installed on most raspberry pi OS's so I highly doubt you have 32bit installed since that would fail to even install since the Pi has an ARM processor

Comment: @Domagalla: Are you running the Node.js script on the Raspberry Pi? I am unable to reproduce your problem. I am using a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian 7.8, node v0.10.41, and python-shell 0.4.0. I also have a USB-to-Serial converter so that I can run your script. My only change is to use `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: yes i am running on raspberry pi but using ArchLinux. the usb port is the right one to me as well. now i elude the problem while directly communicate with the gpios via nodejs

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide some options like the python path and directory containing your script. I would write your NodeJS script like:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

const options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonPath: '/path/to/python',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'],
    scriptPath: '/directory/containing/python/script',
  };

PythonShell.run('ledtest.py', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('finished');
});
```

You can get the python path from your Python3 shell like:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

More information on python-shell options can be found [here](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell)